# Decimation generated unexpectedly high values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I first applied a 100 Hz lowpass filter to my data, which was recorded at 30000 Hz:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as ss
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def butter_lowpass(low_cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_low_cutoff = low_cutoff / nyq
    b_low, a_low = butter(order, normal_low_cutoff, btype='lowpass', analog=False)
    return b_low, a_low

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, low_cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b_low, a_low = butter_lowpass(low_cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y_low = ss.lfilter(b_low, a_low, data)
    return y_low

# Filter requirements.
order = 5
fs = 30000      # sample rate, Hz
low_cutoff = 100 # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

print('Filtering data')
filtered_array = butter_lowpass_filter(array, low_cutoff, fs, order)
```

Then I down sampled my data from 30000 Hz to 250 Hz

```
updated_array=ss.decimate(filtered_array, 12, ftype = 'fir')
newarray = ss.decimate(updated_array,10, ftype = 'fir')
```

And then apply the decimated result to a spectrogram:

```
frequencies, time, Sxx = ss.spectrogram(newarray,sampling_rate, ss.get_window('hamming', bin_size), noverlap=0, nfft=sampling_rate*4)
```

However, the resulted plot showed some signal higher than 100Hz even though I already used a lowpass 100Hz filter earlier.

[image: Plot for reference. X-axis is frequency (Hz), Y-axis is power density]

Is there any explanation for this?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: This is the plot if filtering was not carried out.

[image]

Comment: Your low-pass filter will still only cut at a certain number of db per octave. You could have had a really large signal just above 100Hz.

Comment: Maybe ask over at dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you include the imports?  It's not clear what `ss` is.

Comment: As @wwii said, this is more suited for a dsp site than a programming site.  But if you're going to keep it here, can you include a plot of the frequencies before filtering?  The filter won't stop all frequencies perfectly, so it would help to see what effect the filter is having.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. I have edited the post for clarity and I will ask the dsp site later.